# Merging two dataframes with hierarchical columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

this is my first time using the multi-indexing in pandas and I need some help to merge two dataframes with hierarchical columns.
Here are my two dataframes:

```
col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['w', 'x']])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([4,6]),columns=col_index, index=range(4))

     a         b         c     
     w    x    w    x    w    x
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([2,6]),columns=col_index, index=range(2))

     a         b         c     
     w    x    w    x    w    x
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

When I use the merge method, I get the following result:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', suffixes=('', '_2'), left_index = True, right_index= True ))

     a         b         c       a_2       b_2       c_2     
     w    x    w    x    w    x    w    x    w    x    w    x
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

But I would like to merge the two dataframes on a lower level **with the suffixes taking effect on ['w', 'x']** like in the following :

```
     a                   b                   c               
     w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2
0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: Merge will use liked name columns to merge on if no `on` parameter is specified.   If you are merging on index only, use `join` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` or `merge` with `swaplevel()` or `reorder_levels`. Then use `.sort_index()` and pass `axis=1` to sort by index columns.

- `.join()` is better when you are doing a merge on the index like this.
- `.swaplevel()` is better when there are two levels (as in this case) while `.reorder_levels()` is better for 3 or more levels.

Below are the 4 combinations of these methods. For this specific example, I think `.join()`/`.swaplevel()` is the most pandonic (see final example):

```
df3 = (df1.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1)
       .join(df2.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1), rsuffix='_2')
       .reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=[0, 1]))
df3
Out[1]: 
     a                   b                   c               
     w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2
0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN

df3 = (pd.merge(df1.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1),
                df2.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1),
                how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes = ('', '_2'))
                .reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=[0, 1]))
df3
Out[2]: 
     a                   b                   c               
     w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2
0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN

df3 = (pd.merge(df1.swaplevel(axis=1),
                df2.swaplevel(axis=1),
                how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes = ('', '_2'))
                .swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=[0, 1]))
df3
Out[3]: 
     a                   b                   c               
     w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2
0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN

df3 = (df1.swaplevel(i=0,j=1, axis=1)
       .join(df2.swaplevel(axis=1), rsuffix='_2')
       .swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=[0, 1]))
df3
Out[4]: 
     a                   b                   c               
     w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2    w  w_2    x  x_2
0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: In case you weren't aware: `df.swaplevel(axis=1)` can replace each of your calls to `df.reorder_levels(..., axis=1)` in this case. Just wanted to impart another way of achieving the same result. Here's the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) for the function as well.

Comment: Thanks @CameronRiddell , yes I was updating my answer with both ways!